# Schedule task depending on its response

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to schedule a task depending on it's response. The task is something like:

```
public Date scheduledTask() {
    Date nextRun;
    // ...
    nextRun = something();
    // ...
    return nextRun;
}
```

How can I make sure that the same task is called again when reaching the `nextRun`?

Thank you.

Comment: This is a good use case of Strategy design pattern. Please check the documentation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern#Example

Comment: Which approach from Spring are you using for task scheduling? As an example [this](http://darthanthony.wordpress.com/2009/07/07/dynamic-scheduling-with-javaspring/) might help.

Comment: Thank you, @nobeh. Unfortunately your link doesn't help me much, I already tried a similar approach but I apparently have no way to reschedule the task depending on its result. I tried playing with both the Spring's Quartz Support and the Spring 3.0's Scheduling Namespace without any luck. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very simple with standard Quartz scheduler API. Inside your `Job` compute `nextRun` time and create a trigger with `startAt()` defined:

```
public class ScheduledJob implements Job {

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        final Date nextRun = something();

        Trigger trigger = newTrigger().
                startAt(nextRun).
                forJob(context.getJobDetail()).
                build();

        context.getScheduler().scheduleJob(trigger);
    }

}
```

Tested, works like a charm.

Comment: Hello @TomaszNurkiewicz, thank you for your help. Your approach seems to be very good, the only thing is that I will have to trigger it manually the first time, when the application starts. What's the best way to do it? Maybe you can show me your Quartz XML configuration? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the ideas mentioned [here](http://www.jroller.com/jurberg/entry/custom_scheduling_in_spring), then you should be able to have:

```
public class GuaranteeSchedule implements Trigger {

  private Future<?> resultForNextRun;
  private TaskScheduler scheduler;

  public void scheduledTask() {
    // 'this' is this trigger that is used by the scheduler 
    // and the method `nextExecutionTime` is automatically called by the scheduler
    resultForNextRun = scheduler.schedule(theTask, this);
    // theTask is the object that calls something()
  }

  // Implementing Trigger to add control dynamic execution time of this trigger
  @Override
  public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext tc) {
    // make sure the result for the previous call is ready using the waiting feature of Future
    Object result = resultForNextRun.get();
    // Use tc or other stuff to calculate new schedule
    return new Date();
  }

}
```

The rest, you should follow the configuration mentioned in the reference. I believe this would resolve the problem of depending the next call of a trigger on the result of the previous. You may also need to be careful about the first call of `scheduledTask` to make sure `resultForNextRun != null`.